# com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListenerjava.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: s4sdk

If I use ODataQueryBuilder in a servlet, I can call the servlet without any problem.

If I incorporated the code in a method and call this method within a ServletContextListener, I got first the following error.

```
2018 02 27 13:17:09#+00#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]##anonymous#fs-watcher#na#afc186d33#firstapp#web##na#na#na#na#Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListenerjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Another strategy was already registered.
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.registerConcurrencyStrategy(HystrixPlugins.java:190)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListener.bootstrap(ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListener.java:43)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListener.contextInitialized(ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListener.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:125)
at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
at org.eclipse.gemini.web.extender.WebContainerBundleCustomizer.addingBundle(WebContainerBundleCustomizer.java:49)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:467)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1568)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1504)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:391)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
at org.eclipse.virgo.web.war.deployer.WARDeployer.start(WARDeployer.java:780)
at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.internal.StandardApplicationDeployer.startDeployables(StandardApplicationDeployer.java:325)
at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.internal.StandardApplicationDeployer.bulkDeploy(StandardApplicationDeployer.java:116)
at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.bulkDeployIfNotDeployed(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:143)
at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.onInitialEvent(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:105)
at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.notifyListenersOnInitialEvent(FileSystemChecker.java:207)
at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.handleInitialFiles(FileSystemChecker.java:177)
at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.check(FileSystemChecker.java:261)
at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.WatchTask.run(WatchTask.java:49)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:807)
```

Followed by:

- One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in
  the appropriate container log file
- Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

This will destroy my Servlet Context Listener and then failed to start web application in NEO.

It is strange because the method is called well and in the log I can see that the method is called without an error.

If I don't call the method in code, the application is starting up well.

Please let me know, how I can solve this issue, because I need to call the S/4 Hana system.

Comment: Could you share how the structure of your ServletContextListener looks like? The error that you see indicates that you try to register another HystrixConcurrencyStrategy...

Comment: Sent you the code by email

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Version 2.0.0 of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK changed the way how `RequestContextListener`s are initialized. It is now be possible to use the following code without additional effort:

```
new RequestContextExecutor().execute(...);
```

**Original answer:**

I guess that you want to run logic in some background task that is not triggered by a user request.

Can you try to wrap the logic calling the S/4HANA system in a Callable  which is passed to the execute method of a [RequestContextExecutor](https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/docs/1.9.2/javadoc-api/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContextExecutor.html)?

For example:

```java
List<SomeData> result = new RequestContextExecutor()
    .execute(new Callable<List<SomeData>>() {
        @Override
        public List<SomeData> call() {
            return new GetSomeDataCommand().execute();
        }
    });
```

Note that this will require a technical user with Basic credentials in the destination configuration; principal propagation is not available in this case.

Also note that if you want to run the background task calling the external system in a `ServletContextListener` during application startup, you have to

- either explicitly register the relevant `RequestContextListener` classes which are also subclasses of `ServletContextListener` (including, if you are using the SAP Cloud Platform Neo environment, initializing the `ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListener`),
- or specify the order of the `ServletContextListener` classes explicitly in the `web.xml` file.

You can register these listeners explictly as follows:

```java
// ensure that the correct HystrixConcurrencyStrategy is used
new ScpNeoHystrixBootstrapListener().bootstrap();

// explicitly register RequestContextListeners
new RequestContextExecutor().withListeners(
    new DestinationsRequestContextListener(),
    new ScpNeoDestinationsRequestContextListener(),
    new TenantRequestContextListener(),
    new UserRequestContextListener()
).execute( /* callable */ );
```

Comment: Happy to hear this! Would you kindly accept the answer?

Comment: Hello [user3170440](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3170440/user3170440), if your issue is resolved, please accept the answer. This is done by clicking the green checkmark on the left side, cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Note that with version 2.0.0 of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK, the way how RequestContextListeners are initialized has changed. It should now be possible to use `new RequestContextExecutor().execute(...)` without additional effort.