# TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant() throws TenantNotAvailableException: Failed to get current tenant: no request available

Tags: multi-tenant, s4sdk

So I followed https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/20/deep-dive-6-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-extend-your-cloud-foundry-application-with-tenant-aware-persistency/

I have a Spring Boot `2.0.1.RELEASE` application running in SCP with xs2 library OAuth 2.0 security. If I create an access token in Postman and call my @RestController directly (reaching the DB), I get this error from TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant():

```
com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.tenant.exception.TenantNotAvailableException: Failed to get current tenant: no request available. This error may occur when trying to obtain the current tenant within tasks that are not triggered by a request, for example, while using a RequestContextExecutor. Note that, on SCP CF, a request is required to obtain tenant information from the JWT bearer in the "Authorization" header.
```

I don't understand why I get no "request available" when I am obviously sending a request with Authorization header containing Bearer token directly to my `@RestController`.

I had an idea to solve this by annotating `TenantIdentifierResolver` class (which contains the TenantAccessor) with `@RequestScope`, but this fails because then the request context is not found when initializing the app (`entityManagerFactory`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message indicates a missing [`RequestContext`](https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/docs/1.11.1/javadoc-api/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContext.html). Such a `RequestContext` is initialized using either a [`RequestContextServletFilter`](https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/docs/1.11.1/javadoc-api/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContextServletFilter.html) or a [`RequestContextExecutor`](https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/docs/1.11.1/javadoc-api/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/servlet/RequestContextExecutor.html).

Your Spring application may be missing the Web Servlet filter. Could you try to add the following `@ServletComponentScan` annotation to your application?

```java
@ServletComponentScan({"com.sap.cloud.sdk"})
  ...
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{ 
    ...
}
```

Within background tasks, you may have to use a `RequestContextExecutor`.
For more details, please also have a look at a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010133/com-sap-cloud-sdk-frameworks-hystrix-scpneohystrixbootstraplistenerjava-lang-ill/49033861#49033861).

Comment: Added the scan annotation, now the `RequestContextServletFilter` is registered, but problem still persists. After some investigation I found out that `HystrixRequestContextFacade` is used instead of `ThreadLocalRequestContextFacade`. For some reason s4sdk is boostrapping Hystrix at startup (`com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.HystrixBootstrapListener` annotated with `@WebListener`). I am not using Hystrix in the app yet. Can you help? I am thinking of registering the `RequestContextServletFilter` manually or changing scan package to `@ServletComponentScan("com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform")`.

Comment: I think you should be able to go with either of the two suggested approaches.

Comment: Hello Michal, if your question was answered, please mark it by clicking the green checkmark, so that people can see this quickly. Thanks, Florian.